# Force Oracle Drop Global Temp Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, temp-tables

In our project I create some global temp table that will be like these:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE v2dtemp (
  id           NUMBER,
  GOOD_TYPE_GROUP       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
  GOOD_CODE             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  GOOD_TITLE            VARCHAR2(250 BYTE)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

but the problem comes when I want to drop this table.
Oracle will not let me to drop the table, and it says:

```
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use
```

I have to use this table in some procedure but it may be changed dependent to other reports. So I should always drop the table then I should recreate it with my needed fields.

I have to use this for some business reasons so it is not possible for me to use tables, or other things. I can use just temp tables.
I tried on commit delete rows, but when I call my procedure to use the data in this table there are no more rows in the table and they have been deleted.

Any helps will greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance

/// EDIT

```
public void saveJSONBatchOpenJobs(final JSONArray array, MtdReport report) {
    dropAndCreateTable();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO v2d_temp " +
            "(ID, KARPARDAZ, GOOD_TYPE_GROUP, GOOD_CODE, GOOD_TITLE, COUNT, "
            + "FACTOR_COUNT, GHABZ_COUNT, DEAL_NO, DEAL_DATE, REQUEST_NO, REQUEST_DATE, "
            + "REQUEST_CLIENT, STATUS, TYPE, MTDREPORT_ID, GEN_SECURITY_DATA_ID) " +
            "VALUES (MTD_KARPARDAZ_OPEN_JOBS_SEQ.nextval,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            JSONArray values = array.getJSONArray(i);
            if(!values.get(0).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(1, values.get(0).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(1).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(2, values.get(1).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(2).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(3, values.get(2).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(3, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(3).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(4, values.get(3).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(4, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(4).equals("null"))
                ps.setBigDecimal(5, new BigDecimal(values.get(4).toString()));
            else
                ps.setNull(5, Types.NUMERIC);
            if(!values.get(5).equals("null"))
                ps.setBigDecimal(6, new BigDecimal(values.get(5).toString()));
            else
                ps.setNull(6, Types.NUMERIC);
            if(!values.get(6).equals("null"))
                ps.setBigDecimal(7, new BigDecimal(values.get(6).toString()));
            else
                ps.setNull(7, Types.NUMERIC);
            if(!values.get(7).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(8, values.get(7).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(8, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(8).equals("null"))
                ps.setDate(9, new Date(new Timestamp(values.getLong(8)).getDateTime()));
            else
                ps.setNull(9, Types.DATE);
            if(!values.get(9).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(10, values.get(9).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(10, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(10).equals("null"))
                ps.setDate(11, new Date(new Timestamp(values.getLong(8)).getDateTime()));
            else
                ps.setNull(11, Types.DATE);
            if(!values.get(11).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(12, values.get(11).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(12, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(12).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(13, values.get(12).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(13, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(13).equals("null"))
                ps.setString(14, values.get(13).toString());
            else
                ps.setNull(14, Types.VARCHAR);
            if(!values.get(14).equals("null"))
                ps.setLong(15, new Long(values.get(14).toString()));
            else
                ps.setNull(15, Types.NUMERIC);
            if(!values.get(15).equals("null"))
                ps.setLong(16, new Long(values.get(15).toString()));
            else
                ps.setNull(16, Types.NUMERIC);
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return array.size();
        }
    });

    String bulkInsert = "declare "
            + "type array is table of d2v_temp%rowtype;"
            + "t1 array;"
            + "begin "
            + "select * bulk collect into t1 from d2v_temp;"
            + "forall i in t1.first..t1.last "
            + "insert into vertical_design values t1(i);"
            + "end;";
    executeSQL(bulkInsert);
}

private void dropAndCreateTable() {
    String dropSql = "declare c int;"
            + "begin "
            + "select count(*) into c from user_tables where table_name = upper('v2d_temp');"
            + "if c = 1 then "
            + "truncate table v2d_temp"
            + "drop table v2d_temp;"
            + " end if;"
            + "end;";
    executeSQL(dropSql);

    String createSql = "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE v2d_temp (\n"
            + "DEAL_ID               NUMBER,\n"
            + "id           NUMBER,\n"
            + "karpardaz  VARCHAR2(350),\n"
            + "GOOD_TYPE_GROUP       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),\n"
            + "GOOD_CODE             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),\n"
            + "GOOD_TITLE            VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),\n"
            + "COUNT                 NUMBER,\n"
            + "FACTOR_COUNT          NUMBER,\n"
            + "GHABZ_COUNT           NUMBER,\n"
            + "DEAL_NO               VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),\n"
            + "DEAL_DATE             DATE,\n"
            + "REQUEST_NO            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),\n"
            + "REQUEST_DATE          DATE,\n"
            + "REQUEST_CLIENT        VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),\n"
            + "STATUS                VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),\n"
            + "TYPE                  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),\n"
            + "GEN_SECURITY_DATA_ID  NUMBER(10),\n"
            + "MTDREPORT_ID          NUMBER\n"
            + ")\n"
            + "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS";
    executeSQL(createSql);
}

private void executeSQL(String sql) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        st.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Global temporary tables are not supposed to be used this way. They should be defined as a part of schema and their structures shouldn't change with each usage/program execution. If you have multiple programs using temporary storage define global temporary table for each data structure you need.

You can also use subquery factoring in your query which can create temporary table in the bacground or force it (with some limitations) using /*+ materialize */ hint.

Comment: My boss insists me using this way, temp tables and etc. so I have no other choices. It is the second day I am searching for any other ways using temp tables and using the data in other sections, can you guide me to some other ways?

Comment: Then your boss does not understand how Oracle works.

Comment: Look for another job. You won't learn anything of value there.

Comment: maybe you are right, but now, in this moment I have to find a way to solve this problem, he is persisting that there is a way to do this, and when I explain more detail that there is no way to do this through temp tables, I make him more angry and he is thinking that I do not know anything about oracle now! I explained more details in first answer's comments, if you have any idea about how can I force oracle to drop some temp table without considering other session's data, I will be so thankful if you share it with me.

Comment: Time and time again I see questions similar to this one and the answer is usually "Oracle is not meant to be used in that manner" and ... boom .... 10 years later Oracle introduces that exact feature. This is not a helpful comment, but just a rant on how OracleDB was engineered.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Oracle global temporary tables are not transient objects.  They are proper heap tables.  We create them once and *any session* can use them to store data which is visible only to *that session*.

The temporary aspect is that the data is not persistent beyond one transaction or one session.  The key implementation detail is that the data is written to a temporary tablespace not a permanent one.  However, the data is still written to - and read from - disk, so there is a notable overhead to the use of global temporary tables.

The point is we are not supposed to drop and recreate temporary tables.  If you're trying to port SQL Server style logic into Oracle then you should consider using PL/SQL collections to maintain temporary data in-memory.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00501)

The specific cause of `ORA-14452` is that we cannot drop a global temporary table which has session scope persistence if it has contained data during the session.  Even if the table is currently empty...

```
SQL> create global temporary table gtt23 (col1 number)
  2  on commit preserve rows
  3  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into gtt23 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> delete from gtt23;

1 row deleted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> drop table gtt23;
drop table gtt23
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

SQL>
```

The solution is to end the session and re-connect, or (somewhat bizarrely) to truncate the table and then drop it.

```
SQL> truncate table gtt23;

Table truncated.

SQL> drop table gtt23;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

If some other session is using the global temporary table - and that is possible (hence the *global* nomenclature) then you won't be able to drop the table until all the sessions disconnect.

So the real solution is to learn to use global temporary tables properly: create specific global temporary tables to match each report.  Or, as I say, use PL/SQL collections instead.  Or, even, just learn to write well-tuned SQL.  Often we use temporary tables as a workaround to a poorly-written query which could be saved with a better access path.

---

Having looked at your full code, the flow seems even more bizarre:

1. Drop and re-create a global temporary table
2. Populate temporary table
3. Select from temporary table into PL/SQL array
4. Insert into actual table using bulk insert from PL/SQL array

There's so much overhead and wasted activity in here.  All you need to do is take the data you insert into `v2d_temp` and directly populate  `vertical_design`, ideally with an INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM statement.  You will require some pre-processing to convert a JSON array into a query but that is easy to achieve in either Java or PL/SQL.

It seems certain to me that global temporary tables are not the right solution for your scenario.

---

> "our boss or other persons persist to do something through their way, so you cannot change that"

What you have is a **Boss Problem** not a **Programming Problem**.  Consequently it is off-topic as far as StackOverflow goes.  But here are some suggestions anyway.

The key thing to remember is that we are not talking about a compromise on some sub-optimal architecture: what your boss proposes clearly *won't work* in a multi-user environment.  so, your options are:

1. Ignore the `ORA-14452` error, proceed into production and then use the "but you told me to" defence when it all goes horribly wrong.  This is the weakest play.
2. Covertly junk the global tables and implement something which will work in a multi-user scenario.  This is high-risk because you have no defence if you botch the implementation.
3. Speak to your boss.  Tell them you're running into the `ORA-14452` error, say you have done some investigation and it appears to a fundamental issue with using global temporary tables in this fashion but obviously you've overlooked something.  Then, ask them how they got around this problem when they've implemented it before.  This can go several ways, maybe they have a workaround, maybe they'll realise that this is the wrong way to use global temporary tables, maybe they'll tell you to get lost.  Either way, this is the best approach: you've raised concerns to the appropriate level.

Good luck.

Comment: no there is another problem, there is a procedure that I do not call that in the code, the procedure will change the data, and insert it in another global temp table 'd2v_temp'. there are two tables, one v2d_temp and the other d2v_temp, one is for my data, and the other is for the converted data by procedure. procedure will read data from d2v_temp and convert it and put the new data into v2d_temp.

Comment: The more details you provide the less this seems like a problem which needs global temporary tables.  The fact that you are being told to use them by your boss means this is a political problem not a technical one, and so beyond our remit.

Comment: I know that is a political problem, but my question is about finding an answer to the question : Is there any way for dropping a global temporary table that is dependent to session in oracle? If we have such a way to do that, my problem is resolved.

Comment: Of course you have been in some situation like me that your boss or other persons persist to do something through their way, so you cannot change that, you can just use some special ways or some tricks so you can do the thing in the dirty way!

Answer (score 6):

Killing sessions is the only way to work around ORA-14452 errors.  Use the data dictionary to find other sessions using the temporary table and kill them
 with a statement like `alter system kill session 'sid,seriall#,instance_id';`.

This is the "official" solution mentioned in the Oracle support document
 *HOW TO DIAGNOSE AN ORA-14452 DURING DROP OF TEMPORARY TABLE (Doc ID 800506.1)*.  I've successfully used this method in the past, for a slightly different reason.
  Killing sessions requires elevated privileges and can be tricky; it may require killing, waiting, and trying again several times.

This solution is almost certainly a bad idea for many reasons.  Before you implement this, you should try to leverage this information as proof that this is
 the wrong way to do it.  For example, "Oracle documentation says this method requires `alter system` privilege, which is dangerous and raises some
 security issues...".

Comment: Does it effect other users if I close the session, or can it make some problems for the entire application running on tomcat 6.0?

Comment: Oh yes, killing sessions is very dangerous and can cause all kinds of problems.  It's extremely rare to have an application kill sessions.  It's the only way to make this work but I'm not really proposing you do that.  Instead, you might want to mention it to your DBA; they will probably insist you find another approach.

Comment: fortunately, this task is off of me, and he assigned it to another person, he has found that this cannot be happen too, so we will discuss again to change the way we want to implement this task

Answer (score 4):

Another approach worth considering here is to rethink whether you need a temporary table at all.

It is a very common programming practice among those who transition from other RDBMSs to Oracle to overuse them, because they do not understand that you can use such features as Common Table Expressions to implicitly materialise a temporary result set that can be referenced in other parts of the same query, and on other systems it has become natural to write data to a table and then select from it.

The failure is usually compounded by not understanding that PL/SQL-based row by row processing is inferior in almost every respect to SQL-based set processing -- slower, more complex to code, more wordy, and more error prone -- but Oracle presents so many other powerful features for SQL processing that even when it is required it can generally be integrated directly into a SQL SELECT statement anyway.

As a side-note, in 20 years of writing Oracle code for reporting and ETL, I only needed to do use row-by-row processing once, and never needed to use a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all running sessions by running:

```
SELECT * FROM V$SESSION
```

To kill a session, you have a few options. The following command waits for the current in-flight transactions to complete before disconnecting:

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION ‘sid,serial#’ POST_TRANSACTION
```

While the following command is just like kill -9; it wipes the O/S process out:

```
ALTER SYSTEM DISCONNECT SESSION ‘sid,serial#’ IMMEDIATE
```

The latter is the most efficient in killing the session that is preventing you from removing a temp table. However, use with caution, as it's a pretty brute force function. Once the session is terminated, you can remove the temp table without getting errors.

You can read more about the different ways of killing a session here (I'm not affiliated with this website, I came across it myself when I had a similar problem to yours):
https://chandlerdba.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/killing-a-session-dead/