# drop global temporary table (attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary...)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have asked a question similar to this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423397/force-oracle-drop-global-temp-table/32448960) which I found that my problem is not a programming problem and it is a boss problem. I changed the way so I am trying to create and drop a global temp table which on commit preserve rows. All in one procedure. So as I know the session should not change. But the problem is that when I insert no data in the table the drop works fine, but when I insert some data in the table it shows me the exception below:
    attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use

The first procedure:

```
select count(*) into int_var from user_tables where table_name = upper('v2d_temp');      
    if int_var = 1
    then
            execute immediate ('truncate table v2d_temp');
            execute immediate ('drop table v2d_temp');
    end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('drop v2d');
    -- create temp table
    execute immediate ('CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE v2d_temp (
            DEAL_ID               NUMBER,
            id           NUMBER,
            karpardaz  VARCHAR2(350),
            karpardaz_id number,
            GOOD_TYPE_GROUP       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            GOOD_CODE             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            GOOD_TITLE            VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            COUNT                 NUMBER,
            FACTOR_COUNT          NUMBER,
            GHABZ_COUNT           NUMBER,
            DEAL_NO               VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            DEAL_DATE             DATE,
            REQUEST_NO            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            REQUEST_DATE          DATE,
            REQUEST_CLIENT        VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            STATUS                VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            TYPE                  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            GEN_SECURITY_DATA_ID  NUMBER(10),
            MTDREPORT_ID          NUMBER
            ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS');
execute immediate ('drop table v2d_temp');
```

it will work fine, but when I change the procedure and put an insert query, this will show the error:

```
select count(*) into int_var from user_tables where table_name = upper('v2d_temp');      
    if int_var = 1
    then
            execute immediate ('truncate table v2d_temp');
            execute immediate ('drop table v2d_temp');
    end if;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('drop v2d');
    -- create temp table
    execute immediate ('CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE v2d_temp (
            DEAL_ID               NUMBER,
            id           NUMBER,
            karpardaz  VARCHAR2(350),
            karpardaz_id number,
            GOOD_TYPE_GROUP       VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            GOOD_CODE             VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            GOOD_TITLE            VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            COUNT                 NUMBER,
            FACTOR_COUNT          NUMBER,
            GHABZ_COUNT           NUMBER,
            DEAL_NO               VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            DEAL_DATE             DATE,
            REQUEST_NO            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
            REQUEST_DATE          DATE,
            REQUEST_CLIENT        VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            STATUS                VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            TYPE                  VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
            GEN_SECURITY_DATA_ID  NUMBER(10),
            MTDREPORT_ID          NUMBER
            ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS');
insert into v2d_temp values (
                            null,
                            1,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            4,
                            null);
execute immediate ('drop table v2d_temp');
```

I have no idea what to do or why this is happening, I have not any other session to have some private data, so it just what you see. I create it, insert some data, then I drop it, but I cannot understand the error or the cause of it.

If you wanna ask why I am creating a temp table and dropping that at the end, there are just some business reasons and there will be some codes between them, but for now I delete all the queries but the result is the same and it does not depend on what is between the query, when I insert just one row to table, I cannot drop it anymore.
I am working on it for some days, and I have no idea how to that.
Any help will greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Truncate` table before dropping the table

Comment: Yeah it works for now, thank you @Praveen, I cannot understand why I did not test it before!

Comment: Particularly hard to understand given that answers in your previous question explicitly include advice to truncate the table as a workaround to this error.

Comment: @APC After three days of working with this problem I think my brain is not working well :|