# ORA-001031 Insufficient privileges when executing statement from stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a `CREATE TABLE` statement that when I execute it from an anonymous block works fine, but when I put the same script in a stored procedure that is defined in a package I have the message :

> ORA-001031 Insufficient privileges

My statement inside an anonymous block (no error) :

```sql
DECLARE
v_start_date DATE;
v_end_date DATE;
v_statement VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tmp_TABLE_X';
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
          RAISE;
        END IF;
v_start_date := TO_DATE('2016/10/31 16:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
v_end_date := TO_DATE('2016/11/30 15:59:59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
v_statement := 'CREATE TABLE tmp_TABLE_X AS (
    SELECT o.ID, o.NAME, o.PARENT, o.START_DATE, o.END_DATE, o.EDIT_DATE
    FROM MyTable o
    WHERE o.PARENT IS NOT NULL AND o.START_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('''|| TO_CHAR(v_start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') || ''',''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')
    AND TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR(v_end_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') || ''',''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') )';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_statement;
END;
```

My statement inside a stored procedure (error) :

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG1 AS
/* Other definitions */
PROCEDURE LOAD_TMP_DATA(p_start_date IN VARCHAR2, p_end_date IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
    v_start_date DATE;
    v_end_date DATE;
    v_statement VARCHAR2(3000);
    BEGIN
      v_start_date := TO_DATE(p_start_date||' 16:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
      v_end_date := TO_DATE(p_end_date||' 15:59:59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tmp_TABLE_X';
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
          RAISE;
        END IF;
        v_start_date := TO_DATE('2016/10/31 16:00:00', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
        v_end_date := TO_DATE('2016/11/30 15:59:59', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
        v_statement := 'CREATE TABLE tmp_TABLE_X AS (
            SELECT o.ID, o.NAME, o.PARENT, o.START_DATE, o.END_DATE, o.EDIT_DATE
            FROM MyTable o
            WHERE o.PARENT IS NOT NULL AND o.START_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('''|| TO_CHAR(v_start_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') || ''',''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'')
            AND TO_DATE(''' || TO_CHAR(v_end_date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') || ''',''YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'') )';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_statement;
    END;
END;
```

I can't understand why Oracle is showing this error.

Comment: The canonical way to implement a temporary table in Oracle is to use a [Global Temporary Table](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/oracle-global-temporary-table). You define the table once, put data into it/manipulate it during your session, and then when you disconnect all the data is automatically deleted. (You can also choose to  have the data deleted at the end of each transaction instead of at the end of the session). Each session has their own "view" of the table - they can only see the data they put into it, and cannot access other session's data. Best of luck.

Comment: Dropping and recreating tables is very rare in Oracle and should be considered an anti-pattern. It's a lot more common in T-SQL and I notice your profile features the `[sql-server]` tag. So I suggest you [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324379/146325) which attempts to explain why dropping and re-creating a table is usually unnecessary in Oracle, and what alternative approaches you have.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a table you need the "create table" privilege. It might be that your user has that privilege through a role. However, when executing from a stored procedure you need a direct grant.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-roles-in-oracle-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you're doing it completely wrong. Oracle doesn't work that way.

If I were you, I'd `CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE_X` once (not PL/SQL!), and use it as many times as needed. How?

- instead of dropping & creating it all the time, you'd
- delete (truncate) it and insert new rows using appropriate `WHERE` clause

You can even choose between a "normal" table or a global (or private, depending on Oracle version you use) temporary table.

But dropping/creating/populating it in PL/SQL? What a nightmare! Don't do that.